# Custom django-revproxy permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django-revproxy which proxies requests from my api to another api. How can i separate permissions for users? For example, i have url:

urls.py:

```
url(r'^posts(?P<path>.*)$', ProxyView.as_view(upstream='http://example.com/posts')),
```

For admin i need all GET/PUT/POST/PATCH/DELETE requests on ProxyView, which i get by default, but for custom users i need custom permissions, for example, i need only GET request for one_user on ProxyView, GET/PUT for second_user. How can i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can override view's `dispatch()` method. Do the checks you need and if user is not allowed to perform given request — return response with code 403, otherwise continue normal flow.